# Finding $\int \sec^2 x \tan x \, dx$, I get $\frac12\sec^2x+C$, but an online calculator gets $\frac12\tan^2x+C$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried to find a generic antiderivative for

$$\displaystyle \int \sec^2x \tan x \mathop{dx} $$

but I think there is something wrong with my solution because it doesn't match what I got through an online calculator.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my solution.

> We will use substitution:
>
> $$u = \sec x \qquad du = \sec x \tan x \, dx$$
>
> We substitute and apply the power rule:
>
> $$ \int (\sec x) (\sec x \tan x \, dx) = \int u \, du = \frac{1}{2} u^2 + C = \frac{\sec^2x}{2} + C$$

The solution I found with the online calculator is:

$$ \frac{\tan ^2 x}{2} + C$$

The steps in the online solution make sense also, so I'm not sure what's going on.

The one thing I have some doubts about is whether I derived the $du$ from $u = \sec x$ correctly. But it seems okay to me. I used implicit differentiation with $x$.

Comment: $\sec^2{(x)}=1+\tan^2{(x)}=\tan^2{(x)}+C$ hence these functions differ by a constant...

Comment: What happens if you try $u=\tan \theta?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sec^{2}(x)}{2} + C = \frac{1+\tan^{2}(x)}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\tan^{2}(x)}{2} + C$$

$\frac{1}{2}$ is just another constant, in indefinite integral constant doesn't really matter unless you're asked for the integrand original function so you can just kind of "combine" $\frac{1}{2}$ into C, you can also differentiate the answer to know that there's nothing wrong at all with your answer

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is correct.

The difference between your answer and the answer given is that they differ by a constant value.

You can see this by using the identity

$$1+\tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$$

Hence your answer can be converted to the given answer by subtracting $-1/2$, which is a constant.

As mentioned in the comments and in another answer you can also directly get the form in the answer by using the substitution

$$u = \tan x$$

Comment: I modified your answer a bit to use MathJax. Going forward, please use MathJax for mathematical typesetting for ease of readability. Good answer though!

Comment: Thanks for editing the expressions

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating both of them and see that nothing has gone wrong at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \tan x$.

Then $du = \sec^{2} x dx$.

Hence, the integral becomes

$$ \int u du = \frac{u^{2}}{2} + C = \frac{\tan^{2}x}{2} + C. $$